# Don't forward e-mail message

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

Do you know if e-mail clients support function of Not Forward message? Something in code that disallow for users to share the message?

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible - as your emails are sent using SMTP protocol, you are limited to what it supports. There is no headers or any other technical means letting you to disallow forwarding.

You might have seen examples on how to have Outlook prevent emails from forwarding, but to the best of my knowledge, it is a proprietary feature on Microsoft Exchange.